# Custom graphic item cannot be selected from GraphicScene

Tags: c++, qt

After drawing a circle and an arc on a custom drawing scene, I would like to select the arc.
Strangely, the selection of the arc works fine when I select it from a side QTreeView (displaying the list of elements present on the scene) but I can't select the arc by clicking on it on the scene...

I am having trouble identifying what is the origin of the problem, so any orientation about that would be more than welcome :)

Here is the code of some of the classes implemented :

GraphicArcItem.cpp :

```
#include "graphicarcitem.h"
#include "state.h"
#include "link.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPen>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QStyleOption>

GraphicArcItem::GraphicArcItem(Link *link){
    setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemIsSelectable);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
    m_link = link;
    setStartAngle(0);
    setSpanAngle(270 * 16);
    link->setArcView(this);
}

void GraphicArcItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *){
    QColor myLineColor = Qt::black;
    QPen pen(myLineColor);
        if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        pen.setColor(Qt::blue);
        pen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
        pen.setWidth(2);
    }
    painter->setPen(pen);

    StateView* sview = m_link->getStart()->getStateView();
    QPointF top_left = mapFromItem(sview,
                        sview->getCenterEllipse());
    double x = top_left.rx() - 60.0 - 15.0;
    double y = top_left.ry() - 60.0 - 15.0;
    QRectF rectangle = QRectF(x,y,50.0,50.0);
    painter->drawArc(rectangle, startAngle(), spanAngle());
    x = top_left.rx() - 60.0 - 15.0 - 5;
    y = top_left.ry() - 60.0 - 15.0 - 5;
    QRectF rectangle2 = QRectF(x,y,60.0,60.0);
    painter->drawRect(rectangle2);
}

/*Return the center point of the arc in the parent coordinates*/
QPointF GraphicArcItem::getCenter(){
    int xCenter = rect().x() + rect().width()/2;
    int yCenter = rect().y() + rect().height()/2;
    QPointF center = QPointF(xCenter,yCenter);
    return center;
}

QRectF GraphicArcItem::boundingRect() const{
    StateView* sview = m_link->getStart()->getStateView();
    QPointF top_left = mapFromItem(sview,
                        sview->getCenterEllipse());
    double x = top_left.rx() - 60.0 - 15.0 - 5;
    double y = top_left.ry() - 60.0 - 15.0 - 5;
    QRectF rectangle = QRectF(x,y,60.0,60.0);
    qreal extra = (pen().width() + 50) / 2.0;
    return rectangle
         .normalized()
         .adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra);
}
```

StateView.cpp :

```
#include "stateview.h"
#include "state.h"

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPen>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QStyleOption>

StateView::StateView(State *state, QRectF rect) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect){
    setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemIsSelectable);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
    m_state = state;
    m_rectangle = rect;
    state->setStateView(this);
}
QPointF StateView::getCenterEllipse(){
    int xCenter = rect().x() + rect().width()/2;
    int yCenter = rect().y() + rect().height()/2;
    return QPointF(xCenter,yCenter);
}

QRectF StateView::boundingRect() const{
    qreal extra = (pen().width() + 50) / 2.0;
    return m_rectangle
         .normalized()
         .adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra);
}

void StateView::paint(QPainter *painter,
              const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
              QWidget */*widget*/){
    QColor myOutlineColor = Qt::black;
    QColor myBackgroundColor = Qt::white;
    QPen pen(myOutlineColor);
    if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        pen.setColor(Qt::blue);
        pen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
        pen.setWidth(2);
    }
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(myBackgroundColor);
    painter->drawEllipse(m_rectangle.center(), 60,60);
    QString name = getState()->getName();
    painter->drawText(this->rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, name);
}
```

DrawingScene.cpp :

```
#include "drawingscene.h"

DrawingScene::DrawingScene(QObject *parent)
: QGraphicsScene(parent){
    m_mode = MoveItem;
    m_line = 0;
    m_number_states = 0;
}

/*
 * Creates the stateView element corresponding to the
 * state and adds it to the scene
*/
void DrawingScene::on_drawState(State *state){
    QRectF rectangle(80+ (150 * (m_number_states % 3)),
                 80 + (50 * ((m_number_states / 3) % 7)),
                 120.0, 120.0);
    StateView *sview = new StateView(state, rectangle);
    addItem(sview);
    ++m_number_states;
}
/*
 * Creates the linkView element corresponding to the
 * link and adds it to the scene
*/
void DrawingScene::on_drawLink(Link *link){
    if(link->getStart() == link->getEnd()){
        GraphicArcItem *lview = new GraphicArcItem(link);
        addItem(lview);
    }else{
        LinkView *lview = new LinkView(link);
        addItem(lview);
    }
}

void DrawingScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    if (m_mode == InsertLine){
        m_line = new QGraphicsLineItem(QLineF(event->scenePos(),
                                        event->scenePos()));
        m_line->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::black),2));
        addItem(m_line);
    }
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void DrawingScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    if (m_mode == InsertLine && m_line != 0){
        QLineF newLine(m_line->line().p1(), event->scenePos());
        m_line->setLine(newLine);
    }else{
        QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
}

void DrawingScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    if(m_line != 0 && m_mode == InsertLine){
        QList<QGraphicsItem *> startItems = items(m_line->line().p1());
        if (startItems.count() && startItems.first() == m_line){
            startItems.removeFirst();
        }
        QList<QGraphicsItem *> endItems = items(m_line->line().p2());
        if (endItems.count() && endItems.first() == m_line){
            endItems.removeFirst();
        }
        removeItem(m_line);
        delete m_line;

        if (startItems.count() > 0 && endItems.count() > 0){
            StateView *first = dynamic_cast<StateView *>(startItems.first());
            StateView *last = dynamic_cast<StateView *>(endItems.first());
            if(first && last){
                if(first != last){
                    emit createLink(first->getState(), last->getState());
                }else{
                    emit createLink(first->getState());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    m_line = 0;
    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

And here are some of the images of the result :

Thank youo in advance for your help or orientation :)
[image][image][image]

Comment: You override `boundingRect`, and map coordinate systems there. That's a bit wired, as the bounding rect should be in item coordinates... Qt uses that for hit tests, so I assume that's causing your problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The problem is I don't know how to define the rectangle boundingRect() should return other than with the StateView coordinates :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics Items should not depend on each other like you do in your code. They should be self-contained, especially concerninng bounding boxes and drawing (and possibly shape).

Relative postioning is achieved through parent-child relationships.

So what I suggest is that you redesign your arc item to be independent of the state view, and add it as stateview's child if needed, with the approriate offset.

The bounding rect is the rect around the item's position, in which all the drawing will occur (and is the base for hit tests). It doesn't really matter how you offset the bounding rect, but convention is, that the item's position is the bounding rect's center (exception: QGraphicsPixampItem), e.g.

```
void GraphicArcItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *){
    /* setup painter */

    QRectF rectangle = QRectF(-25.0,-25.0,50.0,50.0);
    painter->drawArc(rectangle, startAngle(), spanAngle());
    QRectF rectangle2 = QRectF(-30.0,-30.0,60.0,60.0);
    painter->drawRect(rectangle2);
}

QRectF GraphicArcItem::boundingRect() const{
    QRectF rectangle = QRectF(-30.0,-30.0,60.0,60.0);
    qreal extra = (pen().width() + 50) / 2.0;
    return rectangle
         .normalized()
         .adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra);
}
```

When adding an arc, create it as a child and offset as needed:

```
void DrawingScene::on_drawLink(Link *link){
    if(link->getStart() == link->getEnd()){
        GraphicArcItem *lview = new GraphicArcItem(link);
        lview->setParentItem(link->getStart()->getStateView());
        lview->setPos(-37.5,-37.5)
        addItem(lview);
    }else{
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can extend the arc's constructor to take the parent item and forward it to the base class (it will become the parent).

Note that I didn't test this, and that coordinates might be off

Comment: Thank you so much for this complete and detailled answer !
I am gonna rethink my design and run some tests with the indication you gave me
I'll let you know my progress ! :)